# JPA (EclipseLink 2.4) not always loading child object

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2 with integrated EclipseLink JPA implementation. My problem is that child object of a specific parent is not always loaded (sometimes it is, sometimes it is not). I'm also using Jax-RS and Jax-b. I'm also using SQLite as database.
The weird thing is that if I restart glassfish  (couple of times), or just refresh my page few times, everything is loaded normally.

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private String lat;
    @NotNull
    private String lon;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    private Beer beer;
    // getters & setters

@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Beer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private String description;
    @NotNull
    private Date added;
    @NotNull
    private String pic;

    private int rateAroma; // type1
    private int rateAlcoholContent; // type2
    private int rateFlavour; // type3

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "beer")
    private Collection<Comment> comments;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "beer")
    private Collection<Rate> ratings;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "beer")
    private Collection<Location> locations;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BEER_ID", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<User> users;

    // I've only included get/set methods of attributes which are marked @XmlTransient

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Comment> getComments() {
    return comments;
    }

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SqlDateAdapter.class)
    public Date getAdded() {
    return added;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Rate> getRatings() {
    return ratings;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Location> getLocations() {
    return locations;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
    }
```

REST Service

```
@GET
@Path("/beers/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Location> getMarkedLocations(@PathParam("id") int locationId) {
    String locationName = null;
    try {
        locationName = locdao.getLocation(locationId).getName();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("no such location");
        return null;
    }
    List<Location> locations = locdao.getLocationsAndBeers(locationName);
    return locations;
}
```

LocationDAO

```
public List<Location> getLocationsAndBeers(String param) {
    em = DB.getDBFactory().createEntityManager();
    List<Location> locations = null;
    try {
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT l FROM Location l WHERE l.name = :name",     Location.class);
        q.setParameter("name",param);
        locations = (List<Location>)q.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
    return locations;
}
```

Database

```
 ID LOCATION_NAME       BEER_ID USER_ID
 10 location name       3       1
 11 location name       4       2
 60 location name      53      51
 61 location name      54      52
 62 beer bar            3       1
```

What I'm trying to do is get all locations from databse which have the same name as location which id I passed in url. I try to manipulate my SQL with INNER JOINS, LEFT JOINS, LEFT JOINS FETCH, etc but the problem remains.

Here is my JSON of what I should get If location id is 61

```
{"location":{"beer":{"added":"2013-04-29 18:17:39","description":"DESC","id":"3","name":"beer_name","pic":"url b1","rateAlcoholContent":"3","rateAroma":"4","rateFlavour":"3"},"id":"62","name":"beer bar","user":{"email":"u1@email","fbid":"0","id":"1","lastName":"lastname u1","name":"name u1","username":"u1"}}}
```

What I get sometimes. There is no Beer object.

```
{"location":{"id":"62","name":"beer bar","user":{"email":"u1@email","fbid":"0","id":"1","lastName":"lastname u1","name":"name u1","username":"u1"}}}
```

Comment: If you ManyToOne was LAZY then it may not be loaded, but since the default is EAGER, you should see the beer as always loaded. Check the result of your query, does getBeer() return something?

Comment: I was thinking about load mode too but I am not sure that's the problem. Now I added out.print in console printing beer object of location and the problem is gone. But still, this is not a proper solution.

Comment: I tried with selecting other locations from db and found out that printing them or any child objects does NOT solve this problem. You were right, getBeer() does not return anything. Child objects sometimes just aren't loaded although the guery is the same.